# Swap the values of two variables using the tuple unpacking style

Tags: dart

In Python, you can swap the values of two variables using the following syntax

```
a, b = b, a
```

How to do this in Dart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python style tuple unpacking is not supported in Dart. Neither is the assignment of multiple variables as you have in your example. If it is the swap you are after, you could always just do the following:

```
var a = 10, b = 5, temp;
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Comment: Not supported, yet... Star this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10310)

Answer (score 6):

It's possible on Dart 3, using **record pattern** feature.

```dart
var (a, b) = ('left', 'right');
(b, a) = (a, b); // Swap!
print('$a $b'); // Prints "right left".
```

[Reference](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/0546-patterns/feature-specification.md#destructuring)

Answer (score 0):

As Shailen Tuli has mentioned, Python-style tuple unpacking is not supported in Dart. You can use `Immediately invoked closures`.

```
(tmp) {
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}(a)
```

Which will do the trick.
Thanks to Mr. [Randal Schwartz](https://discord.com/channels/420324994703163402/825211448598331392/1054125328286633984)

Answer (score -2):

I tried this:

```
swapper(int a,int b)
{
   return {
     "data":
       {
         'b' : b,
         'a' : a
       }
   }['data'];
}
```

Comment: This would return a Map... (and  map['a'] will still be a by the way, to add salt to injury).